# [Error in Signature Verification]:Signature length not correct: got 780 but was expecting 256

Tags: java, base64, digital-signature, x509certificate, xml-signature

Requirement :

Program will have an xml file as input with 3 tags: , and  All these data are Base64 encoded.
Program needs to decode them and verify the data for its authenticity using the signature and certificate

Verified data should be Base64 decoded.

Sign Verification

- Extract the original content, signature data and certificate from the 
  signed file by 
  traversing through the corresponding node.
- Create signature object with SHA256WITHRSA also.
- Invoke the signature verify method with input parameter as signed data, file content and the 
  public key extracted from the certificate node.
- If signer verify method return true then take original file content

This is my code to verify the signature

```
public boolean signAndVerifyXmlDoc(File file) {
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
try {
  docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Document doc = null;
try {

  String orgContent = "", splitData = "", signContent = "", certContent = "";

  doc = docBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(file));
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

  NodeList originalContent = doc.getElementsByTagName("OrgContent");
  Element originalElement = (Element) originalContent.item(0);
  NodeList textOrgContent = originalElement.getChildNodes();
  orgContent = ((Node) textOrgContent.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim();

  NodeList signature = doc.getElementsByTagName("Signature");
  Element signatureElement = (Element) signature.item(0);
  NodeList signatureContent = signatureElement.getChildNodes();
  signContent = ((Node) signatureContent.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim();

  NodeList certificate = doc.getElementsByTagName("Certificate");
  Element certificateElement = (Element) certificate.item(0);
  NodeList certificateContent = certificateElement.getChildNodes();
  certContent = ((Node) certificateContent.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim();


  Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WITHRSA");
  sign.initVerify(getCertificateFromFile(certContent).getPublicKey());
  sign.update(Base64.decode(orgContent));
  byte[] signdDecode = Base64.decode(signContent);
  boolean b = sign.verify(signdDecode);
  return b;
} catch (SAXException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SignatureException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
```

}

So getting the exception when i am verifying the signedData.Please help in finding what i am missing?

Comment: Focus your question on a single problem with less lines of codes and some understandable example data. How do you expect us to read such a huge file of data and debug your code? From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26284855).

Comment: @sanitizedUser updated the question. I just trying to verify the data integrity using the signature and certificate embedded in the xml.

Comment: Ok. It looks better now, but the code is not reproducible. It's just a method. I cannot run it on my machine. Could you provide some small example that could be run here? Maybe with some example XML file as you were saying in the beginning of the question?